# Какая CSS-методология подойдет для маленьких проектов?

Tags: css

Сейчас есть много разных методологий написания CSS-кода, но большинство из них предназначены в основном для крупных проектов. Если ли методологии, которые хорошо подходят, например, для лэндингов?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/256109/, см. заключение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю, что методологии не имеют привязки к размеру проекта. Иными словами, можно использовать БЭМ как для больших, так и для малых проектов. Это всё дело вкуса или требования заказчика. Равносильно не использовать методологии вообще, если нет нужды.